# How to map request contains File and data in Rest service using @RestController with HttpEntity<class> as input parameter

Tags: spring, rest

Please see below code where i want to send request having file and other json data which will be in a single java class:

My Class is(used lombok):

```
@Data
public class CustomFileUploadSearch {

    private Long selectedId;
    private MultipartFile file; 
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/rest/GIER/testFileData", 
    consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity bulkActivateInactivate(HttpEntity<CustomFileUploadSearch> entity, HttpServletRequest request) {

        CustomFileUploadSearch cfuSearch = entity.getBody();
}
```

I am not able to reach into this method.

Please help me so that it has already taken 1 day.

Thanks in advance.

```
@RestController
public class ChassisInventoryRest {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/rest/GIER/testFileData", 
    consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity bulkActivateInactivate(HttpEntity<CustomFileUploadSearch> entity, HttpServletRequest request) {

        CustomFileUploadSearch cfuSearch = entity.getBody();
        System.out.println("cfuSearch.getSelectedId():"+cfuSearch.getSelectedId());
        System.out.println("cfuSearch.getFile():"+cfuSearch.getFile());

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>( new HashMap<String, Object>(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share me your rest controller code

Comment: I have shared my test controller code. please see above

Comment: what is front hand  that you using to send file

Comment: I am using "Postman"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomFileUploadSearch {

   private Long selectedId;
    private MultipartFile file;

    public Long getSelectedId() {
        return selectedId;
    }
    public void setSelectedId(Long selectedId) {
        this.selectedId = selectedId;
    }
    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    } 
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity bulkActivateInactivate(CustomFileUploadSearch  entity, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println(entity.getSelectedId());
        System.out.println(entity.getFile());


}
```

Comment: if its not working let me know i  will tell how it will works

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly get MultipartFile as request input parameter in RestController.

```
@RestController
public class ChassisInventoryRest {
 @PostMapping(path = "/rest/GIER/testFileData", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity bulkActivateInactivate(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @RequestParam Long selectedId) {
    //parameterized constructor
    CustomFileUploadSearch cfuSearch = new CustomFileUploadSearch(selectedId, file);

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>( new HashMap<String, Object>(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```